# TightVNC Server (Windows) make command line configuration persistent

Tags: windows, vnc, tightvnc

I have run the following command for my tighVNC server:

```
tvnserver.exe -controlservice -sharedisplay 1
```

It has worked, but when the computer has been restarted, the setting has been forgotten. What can I do to make changes persistent between reboots?

Best regards,

H25E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot set this option in the Properties of the tightVNC server,
you may run this command on login.

Create a `.bat` file containing the command, and place a link to the file
in the Startup group at:
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Comment: Yes, that's the last resort. But as the TightVNC config is stored in the W10 register, for me it's strange that the configuration isn't persistent. I suposed that I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Try to configure it with Run as Admin.

Comment: Hasn't work, I supose I will do it with the bat file